# How can I mimic `sudo su - user` in a script?

Tags: centos, sudo, su

I need to deploy my app to server called `lovelyplace` by a [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) script. Unfortunately, the server's setup is horrible, but I can do nothing about it - I have to live with it.

There is one non-root user I can use for ordinary stuff, let's name her `alice`. Then there is another user, let's name him `bob`. `bob` has root privilegies. The admin who prepared the server installed all stuff to places where one can operate only as root, so `bob` is needed for practically everything I do.

I have a password only for `alice`'s account. I have no password for `bob`, but I was told I can use his powers by typing `sudo su - bob` and then doing stuff. And that's true - in a shell I can do this (with no password prompts!) and then I am logged in as `bob` and I can do anything. However, I need to do this non-interactively, in a script. Something like `sudo su - bob && whoami`.

But I could not come up with any other way to gain `bob`'s power:

E.g. `sudo su -c whoami bob` results in `[sudo] password for alice:` and then `Sorry, user alice is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as bob on lovelyplace.`

I tried many combinations of `su`, `sudo`, etc., but the result is always the same - password prompt and after that, rejection.

I need to come up with the way to [programmaticaly](http://docs.fabfile.org/) log in to the server as `alice` and then execute stuff as `bob`. I need a non-interactive one liner similar to `sudo whoami`, which would print out `bob`. Otherwise I am not able to deploy my app by script.

Any suggestions how to mimic this strange `sudo su - bob` in script?

**UPDATE:** `bob` does not have the same powers as root. He can't read sudoers, etc., so he has more privileges than `alice`, but apparently not that much to adjust root settings.

Comment: `sudo su -c whoami bob` should work. Are you sure this message isn't from `sudo -u bob whoami`?

Comment: Maybe the entry in the sudoers file is restricting you to only a specific command (`su - bob`). But since you can log in as bob, you can open /etc/sudoers (or a file in /etc/sudoers.d) and add the commands you need.

Comment: @Gilles, I just tried it out and it's "not allowed". @Paulo, I'll have to update the question, because thanks to your suggestion I found out `bob` in fact isn't root. I can't even `cat` sudoers file, so `bob` is apparently quite limited in it's powers.

Comment: @HonzaJavorek What `sudo` permissions do you have, exactly? Only the permission to run the exact command `sudo su - bob`? If so, I agree that the server's setup is horrible! Do you then need to run commands as root? `bob` isn't root, only root is root. Do you mean that `bob` can use `sudo` to run commands as root?

Comment: @Gilles How can I find out what `sudo` permissions do I exactly have? With my new knowledge about `bob` I'd say it's just another user in system, but it has, unlike `alice`, permissions to write and manipulate files and directories where my app should live.

Comment: @HonzaJavorek, you can run `sudo -l` to know what you are allowed on the server.

Comment: `User alice may run the following commands on this host: (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - bob`. Well, I think this explains a lot. This has no solution other than calling the maintainers and saying them there will be no Fabric and they should maybe rather hire some monkeys to write commands instead. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you accumulate your hints into an answer and in conclusion indicate this has no solution other than changing the server setup, I'll accept it.

Comment: @HonzaJavorek, Thanks, but I think the useful hints are already elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Have you looked at `expect`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the commands to be run to stdin of the `sudo su - bob` command (and hence to the shell it creates):

```
sudo su - bob <<ENDCOMMANDS
echo "Running as:"
whoami
echo "done now...
ENDCOMMANDS
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the privilege kung-fu on your server is a quite interesting piece of work. There are two things you can try, but as we can only guess what alice and bob may and may not do, YMMV.

Why does it have to be a script that is run as alice? Because it's some automated access? Well, if there is some cron daemon, you can have a cron job for bob which regularly executes some bash script. If that bash script is writable by alice you found yourself a method to execute scripts as bob without the need for su(do)? voodoo. Yet it does soften security a bit ...

Another approach, I have never tried, goes along the lines of a background shell with stdin and out tied to pipes. It should be possible to send `sudo su - bob\n` to the stdin pipe and it should make the background shell execute that command. Every subsequent command sent to the background shell should be executed as bob. A rough sketch is this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/backshell
mkfifo /tmp/backshell/stdin
mkfifo /tmp/backshell/stdout
mkfifo /tmp/backshell/stderr

bash -l >/tmp/backshell/stdout 2>/tmp/backshell/stderr </tmp/backshell/stdin &

cat /tmp/backshell/stdout &
cat /tmp/backshell/stderr >&2 &

echo "sudo su - bob" >> /tmp/backshell/stdin
echo "whoami" >> /tmp/backshell/stdin
```

However, it has the flaw that after the first `echo` the stdin pipe is closed and consequently the backshell as well. So you must either find a way to keep the stdin pipe from being closed, or you implement it using something a little more sophisticated. I think python as a pretty good module for subshells and interacting with them.

Comment: Another possible hack is to set up a simple setuid script owned by `bob`. Again, this weakens security significantly.